# Minimum number of nodes in balanced binary search tree

Tags: combinatorics, graphing-functions, trees

I'd like to know if anyone could help me verify a recursive formula for the minimum possible number of nodes a binary search tree would require to be balanced. So far, I know that the recursive solution for the maximum possible number of nodes is $M(d)=2M(d−1)+1$, where d is the depth of the BBT. I assume that for the minimum number it may be: $M(d)=2M(d)$ as the non-recursive formula is simply $2^d$. Is this correct, or am I thinking along the wrong sort of lines?

Comment: What is $d$? What do you exactly mean by minimum possible number of nodes?

Comment: Hi, sorry. Should've posed the question better. d is the current depth of the balanced binary tree. The minimum possible number is the number needed for the tree to be balanced. I.e. so that the left and right subtrees will differ by no more than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** You want a minimum node depth $d$ balance binary search tree. What happens if you take a maximum node tree of depth $d-1$ and add a single node?

Comment: The tree gains another level. The subtrees will differ by only one node, so I think this will be the minimum possible number.

Comment: I believe then the solution would be 2(d+1)+1.

Comment: It should just be $M(d-1)+1$, which should be $2^d$ (assuming you've defined depth as distance from root i.e. $M(0)=1, M(1)=3, M(2)=7,...$).

Comment: Ah, my problem was that I wasn't actually using recursion after figuring out the general method for some odd reason.